# Jasmine Get Element is null

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I am working on an existing HTML form in Angular and I need to make a change and add a test.

I am showing content based on the below

```
        <div *ngIf="!showSkeletonRows">
            <ng-container *ngIf="alternateMessageKey; else defaultMessage">
                <ng-container
                    *ngIf="alternateMessageKey === 'dataTable.noDataToDisplayForAssetRequests'; then noDataToDisplayForAssetRequests"></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    

    <ng-template #noDataToDisplayForAssetRequests i18n="@@dataTable.noDataToDisplayForAssetRequests">
        <div class="mt-1 p-2">
            There are no Asset Requests linked to this Title Submission
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #defaultMessage i18n="@@dataTable.noDataToDisplay">
        <div class="mt-1 p-2">
            There is no data to display
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

This is my test

```
describe('VsDataTableComponent', () => {
    let component: VsDataTableComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<VsDataTableComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log('Running my test');
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VsDataTableComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        // Initialize the component with no data
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should display the no data message when there is no data', fakeAsync(() => {
        // Arrange
        component.data = { items: [], metadata: { pagination: { totalCount: 0 } } };
        component.clientSide = true;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // Act
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges(); // Update the view
            console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.innerHTML);
            // Assert
            expect(component.data.items.length).toBe(0);
            expect(component.showSkeletonRows).toBe(false);

            const emptyMessageElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mt-1.p-2'));
            expect(emptyMessageElement).toBeTruthy(); // This fails and is null 
        });
        tick(); 
    }));

});
```

I see there are a few questions on here with similar problems, but I cannot get anything to work to fix this.

This is the error message when testing

> Error: Expected null to be truthy.
> at 
> at UserContext.apply (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/projects/virtusales/shared/src/lib/vs-data-table/vs-data-table.component.spec.ts:905:41)
> at UserContext.apply (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2030:30)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:26)

Comment: Are we to assume that the template decorated with `pTemplate="emptymessage"` is run with the setup you've created in the test?

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, its not safe to assume that. Ive not done angular properly in a few years so am a little rusty

Comment: @HereticMonkey When I am trying to add the template I am getting override issues. 

I will update the question with what I am doing

Comment: @HereticMonkey Im not sure if thats correct or not now though

Comment: Well, you've showed us part of a template of a component (which is not shown at all)... The `*ngIf` directive causes the element to not be rendered if the value is false. So if that template is not shown, that element will not exist, and your selector will not find it.